# How do I automate a vb6 program on an AWS cloud server?

Tags: c#, server, automation, vb6, rdp

I have a vb6 program running on Win server 2016, on AWS. An automation program runs in c#, and button-presses on the vb6 program. The setup acts as a standal8ne server listening and acting on either a port, or http inbound data.

I have found that the vb6 program stops if it is minimised, or if the direct RDP connection is disconnected.

Is there a way to force the automation and vb6 to 'talk' to a virtual screen, so that RDP can be disconnected?

Very grateful for your advice.

Comment: What is the software you are using to do the "button pressing"? This may be an issue there instead of with your VB6 program itself.

Comment: Hi Dave, Thank you. That is an interesting idea. The basic automation routines were written in c#, under SharpDevelop. I'll cross-check which

Answer (score 0):

Create a VB6 DLL instead of a program, and call the DLL from the C# program (using COM-interop). Simplifies the link between the C# program and the VB6 - no more automatically pressing buttons - and removes this issue of the VB6 program terminating.

I'm surprised that disconnecting the RDP connection stops the VB6 program. That doesn't happen when you RDP to a physical machine.

Comment: Thank you, MarkJ. 

To clarify, when the RDP tie is cut, the server animation feature stops responding - the app remains active, but non-responsive.

If the program is minimised - even with RDP connected - the automation stops, as well. It seems that the vb6 app needs to 'see' the user screen, to function.

Comment: Perhaps the "button pressing" part fails, rather than the VB6 program stopping. You could try adding a `Timer` control to the VB6 program, with an event which periodically writes something to a text file. That would allow you to test whether the VB6 program is still functioning.

Comment: Thank you, Mark - for your advice. I am beginning to feel that you are correct in terms of the 'button-pressing' program introducing the difficulties. I'll give the timer trick a whirl & feed back.